# Best Way to import external repo's into Git

Tags: git, svn

On my current project we're using a 3rd party library managed via SVN that I would like to add to our local github for internal management (tracking of the external updates across versions, as well as internal modifications to the library).  In SVN, I've done this with svn import & "[vendor branch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html)" strategies.

I tried something similar in git: Create a repo, clone it local, svn export the library into the local clone, commit & push.  All went fine except the push.  The total repo is about 1.7G, due to large binary files (Graphics, Tarballs, and even some compiled DLL's/SO's/DYLIB's for various platforms).  Yes, I know these files shouldn't be in a Repo but this developer felt otherwise and now I'm stuck dealing with it.  I know binary files aren't git's strong suit (just like every other source control system), but there has to be a way to do it.  Right now, the git-push just won't finish (it sucked up lots of CPU & network bandwidth for about 30 minutes, then sat idle for the next 10 hours).

How do I manage a vendor repo like this with Git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to get a SVN repo is to use the `git svn` subcommands. First do a `git svn clone` (that can take a *long* time, as it has to ask SVN for every single full revision of the repo and construct a `git` repository locally), and keep it up to date with `git svn rebase`. There are severe restrictions on what you can do with such a repository, read the documentation carefully. For casual use it is fine, and given care one can even send patches upstream using `git svn`.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for that. Much nicer way of doing the SVN Import. But will that do any better at managing giant binary files contained within the repo once I add the remote origin & push?

Comment: Giant binary files will be a pain in the neck, whatever VCS you use. If they don't change (often), it's not _that_ bad. I remember some hack on `git` that stashed the files somewhere else, and just kept references (somewhat like symbolic links) in the repository, but not as an officially sanctioned add-on. And that would just add extra complexity, I'd advise against.